# How to escape quotes while inserting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have MySQL table I want to insert data into and wanted to escape quotes and double quotes my current SQL query looks like this

```
/*a function to escape strings*/
function escape_string($string){
    global $connection;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, trim($string));
}

$my_post = [
            "post_title" => escape_string("Title Here"),
            "post_content" => escape_string("content")
            "post_excerpt" => substr(escape_string("Summary"),0, 155),
            "post_status" => "publish",
            "post_name" =>  normal_slugify(escape_string($Title)),
            "post_date" => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
            "post_date_gmt" => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
            "post_modified" => date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),
            "post_modified_gmt" => date("Y-m-d h:i:s")
        ];

    $s_columns = implode(", ",array_keys($post_array));
    $s_values = "'". implode("', '", array_values($post_array)) . "'";
    $query = query("INSERT INTO siri_posts($s_columns) VALUES ($s_values)");
```

Some content have quotes and double quotes so I need to escape them before I insert them to database right?
I tried Using  `mysqli_real_escape_string()` but it's not working and I am getting error when I try to enter title with quotes into the database also the content is user generated so I want I function to escape string before inserting them to database.

I went around the forum and tried a lot of functions but some are `depricated` and some are not working.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of doing this manually, you should be using the parameterized query method that is supported by most database libraries.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userName);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userPass);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

Parameter bindings ensure the datatype of the incoming variable, sanitizes the incoming variable (eg. inserts needed escape character on quotes), and is the main way to prevent SQL injection vulnerability in your application

Comment: i don't understand how the query above is related to my question? and what is userName and Password?? are they database username and password? and also SELECT * FROM Users??? i want to insert but??

Comment: That's very close but still incorrect.